How to Check if a Permission Set Grants Access to an Org-Wide Email in Salesforce

I need to determine if a specific Permission Set in Salesforce has granted access to an Org-Wide Email Address.
My Questions:
Is there a way to query Salesforce to check if a Permission Set has granted access to an Org-Wide Email Address?
If SOQL doesn’t support this, are there other tools (e.g., Metadata API, Apex, etc.) that can help determine this relationship?
Notes:
I am familiar with querying objects like PermissionSet and OrgWideEmailAddress, but I haven’t found a direct link between them.
Any tips on fields or objects to investigate would be helpful.
Thank you for your assistance!
